# Using google oauth2 profile info to set $_SERVER php variables

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I recently migrated from Apache Basic Auth to Google OAuth2. Previously, `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` used to get set according to user's entered information. Now that my page page shows signIn with google, `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` does not gets set. I am able to print user information on the console using

```
<script>function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail())
```

;
However my access control is through userdata.
eg. if user == ABC => add him to white list, 
 if user == XYZ => add him to black list etc. Before google oauth it was done using `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`.

Although I have this information to be printed in console, I need this to check what contents are to be shown to the user and what to hide.There is no information on google on how to use this information server side. The only way (which i dont think is the correct way is to post user info back to server) Below is the code I tried setting `$_SERVER variable`, but seems like there should be a better way to do this. Even this doesnt work.

```
<script>function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  var emailid = profile.getEmail();
         //window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?name=" + emailid;//tried this aswell
        $.ajax({                    
          url: 'myphpfile.php',     
          type: 'post', // performing a POST request
          data : {email:emailid},
          dataType: 'text',                   
          success: function(data)         
          {


                console.log(data); //nothing gets printed here

          }
```

I would also like to show nothing at all until the user signs in with google. Though this can be done later. But currently my own user restriction fails because I am unable to find who is the user who has signed in. myfile.php ->

```
<?php
session_start();
$abc=$_POST['email'];
echo "$abc";
$_SESSION["PHP_AUTH_USER"] = $abc;
$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] = $abc;
?>
```

I just need to get the email id and see if the user should be provided access or not.

Comment: WHy would you use client-side authentication when all of your authentication logic exists server-side?  You can integrate with the OAuth API from server.

Comment: Previously we had to store user password in encrypted form at server. So every time user changes password,  we had to make a change. But with Google login, password checking is done by Google. We only need to provide access restrictions according to user who has logged in

Comment: I understand what you are using OAuth for (3rd party authentication), but don't know why you would choose a client-side javascript implementation rather than an implementation on your server side.  Your server-side code can handle the API integration with Google, that way your server has the ability to inspect the response and apply appropriate permissions.

Comment: Yes,  I'm am unable to get userinfo at my server. That's what my exact problem is

Comment: @MikeBrant it is definitely easier to implement the signin client side.  more available code, better examples, simpler workflow.  on the other hand, a mixed environment, with client and server side operations does have its benefits.  after user signs in explicitely and goes about his or her activities, clientside instructs serverside to do some background stuff.  it does make sense, though it could certainly be implemented as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this using httprequests and curl

```
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<YOURclientID>">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script>
      function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
      }
      function disassociate() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.disconnect().then(function () {
            console.log('User disconnected from association with app.');
        });
    }
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!  Use idToken below
            console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
            console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
            // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
            var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://yourdomain/tokenIdRequest.php');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onload = function() {
              console.log('NEW Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
            console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="login-button" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <div><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" onclick="disassociate();">Disassociate App and Site (easily undone)</a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the receiving php can address the issue by searching googles api directly, sending the onetime access token and receiving all info back.  this way, you avoid bruteforce username hacking

```
<?php
$inputRaw =  file_get_contents('php://input');
$idToken= substr($inputRaw,8);
//$fp = fopen('twoStepOutput.txt', 'a');
//fwrite($fp, date("DATA: YmdHis")."\r\n$idToken\r\n");
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token='.$idToken;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($ch);
//fwrite($fp, "response:[$json]\r\n");
print_r($json); // sends answer back to JS frontend
//fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ajax after signin (implement a callback).  google offers an ajax script for doing this.

```
<!-- BEGIN Pre-requisites -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer>
</script>
<!-- END Pre-requisites -->
```

what you are looking for is explained [in this google developer tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow)

```
<script>
function signInCallback(authResult) {
 if (authResult['code']) {

  // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
  $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

  // Send the code to the server
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://example.com/storeauthcode',
   contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
   success: function(result) {
    // Handle or verify the server response.
    },
   processData: false,
   data: authResult['code']
  });
 } else {
  // There was an error.
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking to do this via PHP, here's how:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes(['email', 'profile']);
```

{ [authenticate...](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/idtoken.php) }

```
$oauth2Service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo->get();
$print_r($userinfo); // => name, email, etc.
```